# Making a string of text bold after identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
<li>Name: Billy</li>
<li>Phone: 0000000000</li>
<li>Email: info@email.com</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to make all the values (after the semi-colon `:`) bold, like `Billy`, etc.
How do I accomplish this with jQuery?

It should look like this:

- Name: **Billy**
- Phone: **0000000000**
- Email: **info@email.com**

Comment: is there a reason you prefer to use jQuery over markup and css? i.e. span tags around the values with a class that makes them bold?

Comment: Yes Decker, there is.

Comment: The jQuery/JavaScript solution is going to be to simply add the tags mentioned by Decker to the markup. It's impossible to do this without adding additional tags to the DOM. What have you tried so far?

Comment: -2 on my question because so many of you failed in your answers? lol please.

Comment: It's not that we failed the question, just provided more logical answers...

Comment: No, -2 on your question because "This question does not show any research effort". You're expected to post your attempted solution, not demand others do your work for you, and you're expected to come up with a *good reason* for throwing out better suggestions, not simply writing them off while telling people to read your question.

Comment: Well you all just messed it up for foozy, because he wouldve had the best answer..

Comment: @ZeeTee How did we mess anything up? He can still have the best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('li').each(function(){
 var c = $(this).text().split(":");
 $(this).html( c[0] + ':<b>' + c[1] + '</b>');
});
```

Comment: For any future viewers, this is the correct answer.  OP threw a fit and refused to accept an answer.  Good job @foozy

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var contents = $(this).text().split(":");
    contents[1] = "<b>" + contents[1] + "</b>";
    $(this).html(contents[0] + ": " + contents[1]);
});
```

It splits the current text on the ":", then adds the tags to the second half.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6vHD/

Comment: This'll put in an extra space. You need to make the center string just ":", rather than ": ". (Also, I just finished writing the exact same thing, so way to go).

Comment: This doesn't render it as HTML, it puts `<strong>` as HTML Encoded, not in format that allows the browser to render.

Comment: Oh, the last line needs to be `$(this).html(contents[0] + ":" + contents[1]);`

Comment: @ZeeTee : use <b> instead of <strong> as latter is an HTML5 tag

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
$(function () {
    $('li').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/:\s*(.+)$/gi, ": <b>$1</b>"));
    })
});
```

Comment: I like this the best, +1 for nice regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: <span>Billy</span></li>
    <li>Phone: <span>0000000000</span></li>
    <li>Email: <span>info@email.com</span></li>
</ul>
```

And use below code

```
$('li > span').each(function(){
 $(this).contents().wrapAll("<b/>");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zFsxZ/2/)

Comment: Short and elegant. I like it, you got a +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(){
   var text = "<b>"+ $(this).text().split(':')[1]+"</b>";
   $(this).html($(this).text().split(':')[0] +": "+ text);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/zFsxZ/3/)

Comment: Does this target only the text after `:`?

Comment: This is the right approach +1, wont this wrap the "Name:" in bold to?

Comment: This does not target the text after `:` -1

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional element, and do it all with CSS:

**CSS**

```
ul li span{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>Name: <span>Billy</span></li>
<li>Phone: <span>0000000000</span></li>
<li>Email: <span>info@email.com</span></li>
</ul>
```

The only way that I see this happening, is by wrapping the text you want highlighted in a wrapper (span, div, etc).  I haven't seen a way to selectively wrap text as bold without a wrapping element.  You can modify the style of the given text, if it's wrapped, with jquery as such...

```
$("ul#somename li span").style("font-weight", "bold");
```

or

```
$("ul#somename li span").addClass('someBoldClass');
```

Comment: I think he needs to do this in js. Not in HTML

Comment: split the input string on basis of (:) and then use <b> tag to bold the text

Comment: I don't get the overall goal or why you would want to do all this in jQuery when it can be accomplished, much easier, in CSS.  So, we can say my answer is wrong, if that's what you're into...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
 <li>Name: Billy</li>
 <li>Phone: 0000000000</li>
 <li>Email: info@email.com</li>
</ul>


$('ul li').each(function(i){
  var litext = $(this).text(); 
  var arrayli = litext.split(' ');
  var bold = "<b>" + arrayli[1] + "</b>";
  $(this).text(arrayli[0] + ' ' + bold);
});
```

Comment: He's just missing another `+` before `bold`.